# Scala: Warn if block of code is executing for more than certain duration?

Tags: scala, akka, future

I wan to do something like this:

```
def warnEvery[A](duration: Duration)(block: => A): A = {
   val start = DateTime.now
   val f = Future(f)
   while(!f.isComplete) {
     Thread.sleep(duration)
     if (!f.isComplete) {
       // Trigger a stack trace warning message
       Log.warn(s"Block is running for ${DateTime.now() - start}", new Throwable())
     }   
   }
   f.result
}
```

The goal is to use the above helper in this way:

```
warnEvery(1 minute) {
  // slow operation
}
```

In my log I want to see a stack trace of a slow block of code.

What is the best way to accomplish this in Scala. Pointers to existing libraries is fine too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use Akka's scheduler to schedule a task that checks on the completion  of the future. This way, there is no need for `Thread.sleep`, which would block its thread until the task completes.

```
def warnEvery[A](duration: FiniteDuration)(block: => A): Future[A] = {
  val start = DateTime.now
  val f = Future(f)
  def warn {
    if (!f.isCompleted) {
      Log.warn(s"Block is running for ${DateTime.now() - start}")
      Akka.system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(duration)(warn)
    }
  }
  Akka.system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(duration)(warn)
  f
}
```

Minor nitpick: Technically, this solution measures the time between the creation of the future and now. If all the threads in the execution context are busy when the future is created, execution of the block might start later. A better log message would thus be "Block has been queued for execution .... seconds ago and has not finished running yet."

Answer (score 0):

Just run the block and in the end check if it has been running for too long

```
import org.joda.time.{Interval, DateTime}
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration

def warnEvery[A](duration: Duration)(block: => A): A = {
  val start = DateTime.now
  try {
    block
  }
  finally {
    val millis = new Interval(start, DateTime.now).toDurationMillis

    if (millis > duration.toMillis) {
      // Log here ...
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT: sorry, didn't understand your question correctly. Then you can do it using a timer-

```
import java.util.{TimerTask, Timer}

import org.joda.time.{Interval, DateTime}
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration

def warnEvery[A](duration: Duration)(block: => A): A = {
  val task = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    def run() {
      // Log here
    }
  }

  val timer = new Timer()
  val delay = duration.toMillis
  val intevalPeriod = duration.toMillis

  timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, delay, intevalPeriod)

  try {
    block
  }
  finally {
    timer.cancel()
  }
}
```

Comment: Does not answer the question. I want it to print at every duration interval while a block is running